# Hungerford's notation of $(|G|,|H|)=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, cyclic-groups, direct-product

I'm working on exercise p63,#5 in Hungerford's Algebra under Graduate Texts in Mathematics. It states that

> "Let $G$, $H$ be finite cyclic groups. Then $G \times H$ is cyclic if and only if $(|G|,|H|) = 1$."

Can someone tell me what the $(|G|,|H|) = 1$ is? I can't get ahold of my professor during spring break. I also couldn't find the same notation in chapter 8. Thanks!!

Comment: Indeed, that is a deficient notation for greatest common divisor. Looks exactly like an ordered pair. Vastly better to just add the three characters "gcd" in front, and then (at least in English) no one will have any doubts.

Comment: The problem is that this used to be a very standard notation, with which all students would have been familiar - it was when I was student many years ago. But for whatever reason it seems not to be so standard any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the greatest common divisor of the two quantities $|G|$ and $|H|$ is $1$.

In more detail: $(a,b)$ denotes the gcd of $a$ and $b$ and $|G|$ is the order of the group $G$.

Comment: omg thx! I thought it is gcd at first but then corrected myself since it doesn't literally has the g.c.d before the parenthesis!

Comment: No problem, happy to help, sometimes people use that notation, and they sometimes also use $[a,b]$ to denote the lcm of $a$ and $b$.